# Simple modules for universal enveloping algebras and Weyl algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $A$ be the universal enveloping algebra of a fintie dimensional Lie algebra (simple if needed) or the Weyl algebra.

> Question: Are there recent survey articles about the (possibly infinite dimensional) simple modules of those algebras?

For what Lie algebras is a complete list of all simple modules known?

Comment: I believe this is essentially a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/q/18559/41291; on the other hand, it was ten years ago, so...